# Error message in terminal when installing pip install xlwt

Tags: python, terminal, installation, pip, xlwt

I downloaded pip via terminal and then after it was downloaded entered "pip install xlwt
 and I get the following error message...

```
Nishons-MacBook-Pro:~ nishon$ pip install xlwt
Collecting xlwt
  Downloading xlwt-0.7.5.tar.gz (115kB)
    100% |################################| 118kB 737kB/s 
Installing collected packages: xlwt
  Running setup.py install for xlwt
    error: could not create '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/xlwt': Permission denied
    Complete output from command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/var/folders/x4/fr2l9c7d303146hw0j1hd16c0000gn/T/pip-build-e3QAt5/xlwt/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/x4/fr2l9c7d303146hw0j1hd16c0000gn/T/pip-vjmP8d-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib
    creating build/lib/xlwt
    copying xlwt/__init__.py -> build/lib/xlwt
    copying xlwt/antlr.py -> build/lib/xlwt
    copying xlwt/BIFFRecords.py -> build/lib/xlwt
    copying xlwt/Bitmap.py -> build/lib/xlwt
    copying xlwt/Cell.py -> build/lib/xlwt
    copying xlwt/Column.py -> build/lib/xlwt
    copying xlwt/CompoundDoc.py -> build/lib/xlwt
    copying xlwt/ExcelFormula.py -> build/lib/xlwt
    copying xlwt/ExcelFormulaLexer.py -> build/lib/xlwt
    copying xlwt/ExcelFormulaParser.py -> build/lib/xlwt
    copying xlwt/ExcelMagic.py -> build/lib/xlwt
    copying xlwt/Formatting.py -> build/lib/xlwt
    copying xlwt/Row.py -> build/lib/xlwt
    copying xlwt/Style.py -> build/lib/xlwt
    copying xlwt/UnicodeUtils.py -> build/lib/xlwt
    copying xlwt/Utils.py -> build/lib/xlwt
    copying xlwt/Workbook.py -> build/lib/xlwt
    copying xlwt/Worksheet.py -> build/lib/xlwt
    creating build/lib/xlwt/doc
    copying xlwt/doc/xlwt.html -> build/lib/xlwt/doc
    creating build/lib/xlwt/examples
    copying xlwt/examples/big-16Mb.py -> build/lib/xlwt/examples
    copying xlwt/examples/big-35Mb.py -> build/lib/xlwt/examples
    copying xlwt/examples/blanks.py -> build/lib/xlwt/examples
    copying xlwt/examples/col_width.py -> build/lib/xlwt/examples
    copying xlwt/examples/country.py -> build/lib/xlwt/examples
    copying xlwt/examples/dates.py -> build/lib/xlwt/examples
    copying xlwt/examples/format.py -> build/lib/xlwt/examples
    copying xlwt/examples/formula_names.py -> build/lib/xlwt/examples
    copying xlwt/examples/formulas.py -> build/lib/xlwt/examples
    copying xlwt/examples/hyperlinks.py -> build/lib/xlwt/examples
    copying xlwt/examples/image.py -> build/lib/xlwt/examples
    copying xlwt/examples/merged.py -> build/lib/xlwt/examples
    copying xlwt/examples/merged0.py -> build/lib/xlwt/examples
    copying xlwt/examples/merged1.py -> build/lib/xlwt/examples
    copying xlwt/examples/mini.py -> build/lib/xlwt/examples
    copying xlwt/examples/num_formats.py -> build/lib/xlwt/examples
    copying xlwt/examples/outline.py -> build/lib/xlwt/examples
    copying xlwt/examples/panes.py -> build/lib/xlwt/examples
    copying xlwt/examples/parse-fmla.py -> build/lib/xlwt/examples
    copying xlwt/examples/protection.py -> build/lib/xlwt/examples
    copying xlwt/examples/python.bmp -> build/lib/xlwt/examples
    copying xlwt/examples/row_styles.py -> build/lib/xlwt/examples
    copying xlwt/examples/row_styles_empty.py -> build/lib/xlwt/examples
    copying xlwt/examples/simple.py -> build/lib/xlwt/examples
    copying xlwt/examples/sst.py -> build/lib/xlwt/examples
    copying xlwt/examples/unicode0.py -> build/lib/xlwt/examples
    copying xlwt/examples/unicode1.py -> build/lib/xlwt/examples
    copying xlwt/examples/unicode2.py -> build/lib/xlwt/examples
    copying xlwt/examples/wsprops.py -> build/lib/xlwt/examples
    copying xlwt/examples/xlwt_easyxf_simple_demo.py -> build/lib/xlwt/examples
    running install_lib
    creating /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/xlwt
    error: could not create '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/xlwt': Permission denied

    ----------------------------------------
    Command "/usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/var/folders/x4/fr2l9c7d303146hw0j1hd16c0000gn/T/pip-build-e3QAt5/xlwt/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/x4/fr2l9c7d303146hw0j1hd16c0000gn/T/pip-vjmP8d-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /var/folders/x4/fr2l9c7d303146hw0j1hd16c0000gn/T/pip-build-e3QAt5/xlwt
Nishons-MacBook-Pro:~ nishon$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `sudo` command when installing packages globally, as your user does not have write permissions to `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages`. Try running

```
sudo pip install xlwt
```

instead.